# Factory of lazy fields

Tags: c#, generics, lazy-initialization

I have a lot of classes and static fields in it, witch has lazy initialization.
The problem is, this static fields are generic, and i always have to write a lot of code just for initialization, like this

```
public static RepositoryOfOrganization<Message> Repository =>
        new Lazy<RepositoryOfOrganization<Message>>(() => new RepositoryOfOrganization<Organization>()).Value;
```

Is there an option to make it in another method, class, or create something like factory, witch will be instantiate field by first call, and return instance by the next calls? Something like that

```
public static RepositoryOfOrganization<Message> Repository => 
MagicFactory<RepositoryOfOrganization<Message>>.Get();
```

Comment: You're probably looking for singleton. Jon Skeet has a great article about it: http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: In case of singleton, i have to write the same code, but in class itself. But i have a lot of them. I need some universal solution. I tried to make it  via reflection etc, but not succeed